# Angular 6 watcher does not compile imported less files in main.less

Tags: javascript, angular, file-watcher

Am working on Angular version 6.

And I am using Less for styling.

In Angular previous Versions, I had to include less main file in angular_cli.json file and that worked perfectly for me.

In latest Angular 6 version we have a file called angular.json and I did the same thing. I have added the main.less file inside styles: [].

But the issue that I am facing is that for some reason when my watcher is running it compiles main.less file alone. Imported LESS files are compiling only when I restart the watcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. 
Run this command

```
npm install --save-dev less-loader@3.0.0
```

and
I add this in angular.json

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "less"
    }
  },
```

This allowed Angular to generate less files by default.

Thank you :-)